# Radio Buttons: weird selection behaviour

Tags: javascript, html

I have been fumbling around with this problem for an hour now and I can't figure out why this strange behaviour in Radiobuttons occurs. The following is my code:

```
<label>Language
  <input type="radio" id="de" value="de" onclick="switchRadioButtons(this);" >de
  <input type="radio" id="en" value="en" onclick="switchRadioButtons(this);" >en
  <input type="radio" id="other" value="other" onclick="switchRadioButtons(this);" >other
  <input type="text" id="language" value="" /><br />
</label>

<script>
  function switchRadioButtons(element) {
    console.log(element.value);  
</script>
```

So, in my opinion, whenever I click on either the value or the button itself, the value of the radiobutton should be written to the console. This works correctly for the button itself, but if I click on the label/description besides the button, it will always print "de" (the first item), no matter what I did (I also tried "switchRadioButtons(document.getElementById('other'));" with no effect).

Can anyone explain to my why this happens and maybe provide a solution?

Comment: input is an autoclosing tag and label can't contain input tags, you might want to try this change first

Comment: Errr... Why all the inputs are enclosed by a label?

Comment: Input being a self closing tag is not related to HTML 5. It's a xHTML thing.

Comment: @MelanciaUK ya right :)

Comment: I don't even see what you can expect when clicking on a single label. If you want to log the currently selected language when clicking on the "Language" label then it's something different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- add a group to your input
- remove label enclosing inputs
- <strike>autoclose input tags</strike> *xHTML thingy...*

Voilà it works :

http://jsfiddle.net/techunter/Z3fU7/

**HTML**

```
<label for="de">Deutch</label>
<input type="radio" name="lang" id="de" value="de" onclick="switchRadioButtons(this);" />
<label for="en">English</label>
<input type="radio" name="lang" id="en" value="en" onclick="switchRadioButtons(this);" />
<label for="other">Other</label>
<input type="radio" name="lang" id="other" value="other" onclick="switchRadioButtons(this);" />
<input type="text" id="language" value="" />
```

**JS**

```
function switchRadioButtons(element) {
    console.log(element.value);
}
```

Answer (score 8):

You have all of your inputs inside the *same* label!  If you click on it, it's gonna trigger the 1st element ('de').  It doesn't know that you wanted to trigger one of the other ones.

You need to have a separate label for *each* element.